# Error when trying to display dataframe using renderDataTable in Shiny

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I am trying to display dataframe using **renderDataTable** in Shiny.

My server.R has the following code:

```
output$table <- renderDataTable(
 summaryActivityDT, options = list(orderClasses = TRUE) 
 )
```

When I run the app, I get the following alert box:

> DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see 
>   http://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7

While debugging (based on url in alert box), I came across the following error:

```
dims [product 75] do not match the length of object [86]
```

p.s. If I replace my calculated dataframe with **iris**, it works fine. However, I do not know what's wrong with my dataframe **summaryActivityDT**.

Comment: Don't you use `renderTable` for that sort of thing?...

Comment: Is summaryActivityDT stored as a dataframe Values or Data? Typically this is a dimensionality issue.

Comment: @VermillionAzure renderDataTable provides some goodies like column sort. Anyway, I managed to find out what was causing the problem.

Comment: @Andrew summaryActivityDT is a dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POSIXlt was causing all the issues. After I changed that column from POSITlt to Chr, everything worked fine.

Thanks everyone. Hope others will find this useful.